# How to check if an uncountable set of functions is linearly independent

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, inner-products

How should I check if an uncountable set of functions is linearly independent? There is an exercise in Cheney's book which is:

> Prove that the set of functions $\{ u_x : x\in \mathbb{R} \}$ is linearly independent. $u_x(t)=e^{ixt}$ where $x$ and $t$ are real numbers.

I know what to do exactly for countable sets but in uncountable sets I'm not even sure what does it mean. Should I use integral?

Comment: Same thing it does for the countable case: if and only if all the finite subcollections are linearly independent.

Comment: well in countable case I'd use Wronskian determinant. what should I do now? if I write an uncountable sum for finite subsets how should I prove that coefficients are 0?

Comment: Whether the ambient space is countable or uncountable, you examine all the *finite* subsets of it for linear dependence.  So, in your case, you would pick distinct real numbers $x_{k}$, $k = 1, \ldots, N$, and prove that the corresponding set $u_{x_{k}}$ of functions is linearly independent.

Comment: @Parto Uhm... You should be careful with that. For a **finite** number $n$ of $C^n$ functions, an identically zero wronskian is a *necessary*, but *not* sufficent condition for linear dependence. If said functions are analytic, then it is also sufficient. However, in the specific case you can apply it.

Comment: @G.Sassatelli right thanks. In general can we say a set is linearly independent if every arbitrary two vectors(or functions) are linearly independent?

Comment: @Parto Nope${}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A set $S$ of vectors is linearly independent if there is no finite, non-trivial linear combination of them that equals zero. You can also think of this as $S$ is linearly independent if and only if every finite subset of $S$ is linearly independent.

So to start proving this, you would take
$$ \sum_{i = 0}^n a_ie^{ix_it} = 0 $$
where you assume that for each $i$, $a_i \ne 0$ and arrive at a contradiction.

---

Note: the reason why we work with finite sums is because infinite sums do not make sense in general. You need some sort of topology that allows you to take limits. There are notions of linear independence that use countable sums (series) but unless you are told this explicitly, you can expect that linear-independence is a statement about finite sums.

Comment: Thanks. So you mean it is enough to prove that the countable finite subsets of this set are linearly independent and that is sufficient to prove my set is linearly independent??

Comment: @Parto Yes, assuming you mean finite. I'm not sure what "countable finite" is supposed to mean; it's redundant if anything.

Comment: @Parto That is the definition of linearly independent.

Comment: @T.Gunn sorry you're right. I meant only finite