# Show $(ev_\alpha)_{\alpha∈\mathbb{R}}$ is linearly independent

Tags: linear-algebra

> Show $(ev_\alpha)_{\alpha∈\mathbb{R}}$ is linearly independent
>
> $(ev_\alpha): \mathbb{R}[X]\rightarrow\mathbb{R}, f\mapsto f(\alpha)$

So I need to show, maybe with a counter-example, that $\lambda=0$ in $\sum\lambda ev_\alpha=0$

How can I do it?

Comment: It's going to be difficult: how come you want to give a counterexample of something that you want to prove? PS: You need to replace $\lambda$ by $\lambda_\alpha$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An uncountable set is linearly independent if and only if [every finite subset is linearly independent](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2306115/how-to-check-if-an-uncountable-set-of-functions-is-linearly-independent/2306119).

So suppose $U \subset \mathbb{R}$ is finite and there exists $\lambda_\alpha$ for each $\alpha \in U$ such that $ \displaystyle \sum_{\alpha \in U} \lambda_\alpha ev_\alpha = 0$.

Then by definition of $ev_\alpha$ we have $\displaystyle \sum_{\alpha \in U} \lambda_\alpha f(\alpha) = 0$ for any $f \in \mathbb{R}[X]$.

Choose some $\alpha' \in U$ and define $\displaystyle f_{\alpha'}(x) =\prod_{\alpha \in U - \{ \alpha' \}}(x-\alpha)$.

Then by construction we have $f_{\alpha'}(\alpha') \neq 0$, but  $f_{\alpha'}(\alpha) = 0$ for all $\alpha \in U - \{\alpha'\}$.

Then $\displaystyle 0= \sum_{\alpha \in U} \lambda_\alpha f_{\alpha'}(\alpha) = \lambda_{\alpha'}f_{\alpha'}(\alpha')$ and since $f_{\alpha'}(\alpha')\neq 0$ we have $\lambda_{\alpha'}=0$.

Since our choice of $\alpha'$ was arbitrary, we have $\lambda_\alpha=0$ for all $\alpha \in U$.

Thus the finite subset $(ev_\alpha)_{\alpha \in U}$ is linearly independent.

And since our choice of $U$ was arbitrary, every finite subset is linearly independent.

Therefore $(ev_\alpha)_{\alpha \in \mathbb{R}}$ is linearly independent.